# Unable to connect to the remote server,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

Simply, I want to send an email in my mvc aspnet application. my action method below :

```
 SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
 NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("my mail address", "my password");
 mailClient.Credentials = cred;
 MailMessage contact = new MailMessage();
 contact.From = new MailAddress("my mail address");
 contact.Subject = "Subject";
 contact.IsBodyHtml = true;
 contact.Body = "Body";
 mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
 contact.To.Add("someone's mail address");
 mailClient.Send(contact);
```

But when I try this I got an error like that :

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : {"Failure sending mail."}

Inner Exception : {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

I searched similar solutions but they say that You needed to set the credentials but I'm sure that I set the credentials correctly. Also Windows Firewall is turned off.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvious question - are you running an SMTP server on your local machine?

Comment: Obvious question 2.0 - are you allowed to connect on the SMTP port (25 or 2525 or 587)? Connection can be blocked by the firewall or the SMTP server itself. Also, which port are you using? Is it the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say it, but your Exceptions are already very obvious!

It seems like u try it on a non SMTP server. Set one up and it should work then.

=>`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : {"Failure sending mail."}`

Else just check your connection/ premission to the server.

=>`Inner Exception : {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}`

Comment: It (the exception message) does not necessarily means that he does not have an SMTP server set up. It **might** mean that the SMTP port he is trying to use is blocked by some software i.e. a firewall. It could also mean that the smtp server is not listening on the default port(25). The bright solution would be trying to connect through telnet to test if a connection is available.

Comment: well i didnt thought about trying to connect through telnet... but it also hasnt to be the port(25) as u say!

Comment: I've disabled ssl and set the root 587 now it works thanks :)